# Powershell Send Email With Images

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am  trying to embed an image into an email to be sent out via Powershell.

Below is the code I have:

```powershell
$Attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($LocalLocation)
$Attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
$Attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
$Attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png"


$MailMessage = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$MailMessage.To.Add($emailTo)
$MailMessage.From = $MyEmail
$MailMessage.Subject = "Test Email"
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $True
$MailMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)

$MailMessage.Body = "
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src='CID:$($Attachment.ContentId)' />
    </body>
  </html>"

$SmtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("123.0.0.1",25 )
$SmtpClient.Send($MailMessage)
```

I get sent an email but there is just an empty box in the message. The $LocalLocation is the link to my image.

I am using Powershell 3

Comment: In the body you are referencing `$Attachment.ContentId` but I don't see you're assigning it a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$SendTo = "Sender Mail ID"
$SMTPServer = "SMTP Server" 
$EmailFrom = “Reciever Mail ID”
$EmailSubject = “Email including images in HTML”
$Image = "Image File"
$Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image)
$att.ContentId = "att"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$body = '<img src="cid:att" />'
$Message.From = $EmailFrom
$Message.To.Add($SendTo)
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.Body = $body
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Message.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($Message)
$att.Dispose()
```

Hope this HEpls.

Comment: IMO `$mailmessage.Attachments.Add($att1)` shouln't be placed before  `$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage`

Comment: I want the image embedded in the body. The `<img src='CID:$($att1.ContentId)' />` is still not working when I put into body. Thanks

Comment: Edited the script. Now you will be able to send image in the body of the message